# Vsphere Terraform data source dynamic blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-vsphere

I am tryig to create disk using a dynamic block to match my template, everything works fine if I hardcode the disk block like that

```
  disk {
    label            = "disk0"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size
    unit_number      = 0
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned
  }
  disk {
    label            = "disk1"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.1.size
    unit_number      = 1
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.1.thin_provisioned
  }  
  disk {
    label            = "disk2"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.2.size
    unit_number      = 2
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.2.thin_provisioned
  }  
  disk {
    label            = "disk3"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.3.size
    
    unit_number      = 3
    
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.3.thin_provisioned
  }
```

However, when using a dynamic block it fails:

```
     dynamic "disk" {
        for_each = var.disk
        content {
            label = disk.value["label"]
            size = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.${disk.value["index"]}.size
            thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.${disk.value["index"]}.thin_provisioned
            unit_number = disk.value["index"]    
        
        }
     }
```

```
variable "disk" {
  description = "My disks. Such disks. Much wow."
    type = list(map(string))
    default = [
    {
      label = "disk0",
      index = 0
      
    },
    {
      label = "disk1",
      index = 1
     
        
    },
    {
      label = "disk2",
      index = 2
      
    },
    {
      label = "disk3",
      index = 3
   
    }
    
    ]
  }
```

Finally, i know the interpolation is wrong, but it seems i can't find the correct form to replace the disk index by a dynamic value.

Any help on that would be very much apprecated.

**EDITED:
POSTED THE ENTIRE CODE**

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user                 = var.vsphere_user
  password             = var.vsphere_password
  vsphere_server       = var.vsphere_server
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
  
}


data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = var.datacenter
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = var.datastore
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = var.cluster
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = var.portgroup
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = var.template_name
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "linux" {
  count             = var.extra_disk_create ? 0 : 1 
  name              = var.vm_name
  resource_pool_id  = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id      = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id

  num_cpus = var.vcpu_count
  memory   = var.memory
  guest_id = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id

  scsi_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type

  network_interface {
    network_id   = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
  }

  dynamic "disk" {
  for_each = local.disk
    content {
      label            = disk.key
      size             = disk.value.size
      thin_provisioned = disk.value.thin_provisioned
      unit_number      = disk.value.unit_number    
    }
}
  
  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id
    linked_clone = "false"

    customize {
      linux_options {
        host_name = var.vm_name
        domain    = var.domain_name
      }

      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = var.vm_ip
        ipv4_netmask = var.vm_cidr
    }

      ipv4_gateway = var.default_gw
      dns_server_list = var.dns_list
      
    }
  }
}
```

**Variables:**

```
variable "vsphere_server" {
  description = "vcentre Server"
}

variable "vsphere_password" {
  description = "Vcentre Password"
}
variable "vsphere_user" {
  description = "Vcentre Username"
}
variable "vm_root_pass" {
  description = "Root password for the VM"
}
variable "datacenter" {
  description = "datacenter name"
}
variable "datastore" {
  description = "datastore name"
}
variable "cluster" {
  description = "cluster name"
}
variable "portgroup" {
  description = "portgroup name"
}
variable "domain_name" {
  description = "domain name"
}
variable "default_gw" {
  description = "domain name"
}
variable "template_name" {
  description = "template to be used"
}

variable "vm_name" {
  description = "vm_name to be used"
}
variable "vm_ip" {
  description = "vm ip to be used"
}
variable "vm_cidr" {
  description = "vm_cidr"

}
variable "vcpu_count" {
  description = "vm_cidr"
}
variable "memory" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}

variable "disk_name" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}
variable "adminpassword" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}
variable "is_windows_image" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}
variable "extra_disk_size" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}
variable "disk_size" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}
variable "dns_list" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}
variable "extra_disk_create" {
  description = "vm memory in megabytes"
}


variable "extra_disk" {
  description = "My extra disks. Such extra disks. Much wow."

  }

locals {
  disk = {
    disk0 = {
      size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size
      unit_number      = 0
      thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned
    } 
    disk1 = {
      size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.1.size
      unit_number      = 1
      thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.1.thin_provisioned
    } 
    disk2 = {
      size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.2.size
      unit_number      = 2
      thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.2.thin_provisioned
    } 
    disk3 = {
      size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.3.size
      unit_number      = 3
      thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.3.thin_provisioned
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you add the data source to the question as well?

Comment: Hi Marko, I dont have any data source for disk, should i have?

Comment: You don't have this: `data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks` anywhere?

Comment: The only place i use it is as the above as example:  
 `disk {
    label            = "disk3"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.3.size
    
    unit_number      = 3
    
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.3.thin_provisioned
  }`

Comment: Well, my answer below should work when you have that defined in your code. But without seeing how you are using the data source, it's hard to know.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE. It worked flawless at the first run. I am unsure now about the data source, as i have reviewed my code and the only place where it is mentioned, is now on the locals as per your example.  
  
here my additional Data sources:  
`data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = var.datacenter
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = var.datastore
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = var.cluster
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}`

Comment: `data "vsphere_network" "network" {  
  name          = var.portgroup  
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id  
}  

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {  
  name          = var.template_name  
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id  
}`

Comment: freaking line breaks

Comment: Not sure I follow. Why would you reference the data source in the question then? Could those values be derived from one of the data sources you mentioned in the comments? What did run flawlessly? Your code or my answer?

Comment: Sorry, i meant your answer. it worked just fine.   
I just mentioned the data sources, because you brought it into the conversation before and i went to double check my code to make sure they were not used anywhere other than my initial snippit.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's the only place you need it then. :)

Comment: I think i executed the wrong code:  
 data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks is list of object with 1 element
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work as you cannot use a list with `for_each`. I would suggest rewriting the variable to have this look and to be a local variable:

```
locals {
  disk = {
    disk0 = {
      size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.size
      unit_number      = 0
      thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned
    } # repeat this for the rest of the disks
  }
}
```

Then in the `dynamic` block you should set the following:

```
dynamic "disk" {
  for_each = local.disk
    content {
      label            = disk.key
      size             = disk.value.size
      thin_provisioned = disk.value.thin_provisioned
      unit_number      = disk.value.unit_number    
    }
}
```

Comment: From this i am having the following error:
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../../extradisk_tfstate/variables.tf line 132, in locals:
│  132:         size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.1.size
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks is list of object with 1 element
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the
│ given index is greater than or equal to the length of the collection.

Comment: Well, please add the data source to the question then.

Comment: Would you please help me with the data source? I am not sure what should it be, looking into the vsphere provider documentation it doesn’t make it any clear to me.

Comment: The one it's complaining about. Just add that block of code to the question so I can adjust the answer. I can't help with the stuff I can't see.

Comment: But based on the error, it's complaining that there is only one disk fetched by the data source with index `0`.

Comment: I just edited the original post with all the content, main.tf and variables.tf
I am not sure what the data source for disks should be as the documentation doesn't make it much clear.